# How to get not own property of object if it's overwrited by own property?

Tags: javascript

For example if I overwrite `constructor` property, how to get original value?

```
var obj = {}
obj.constructor == Object // true
obj = {"constructor": 1}
obj.constructor == Object // false, how to get pointer to Object?
```

Lets say, I got object as it is and it's already with `"constructor": 1` and I can't save pointer to original `constructor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES5 introduced [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf):

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).constructor == Object
```

---

ES6 draft currently contains the `__proto__` property which is implemented by most main browsers (and will most likely ship in IE11), but it is considered non-standard for now:

```
obj.__proto__.constructor == Object
```

Of course, `Object.getPrototypeOf()` is a more cross-browser standard method which suffices for your use case.

Comment: I think `Object.getPrototypeOf` is better than `obj.__proto__`, because `obj.__proto__` can also be overwritten. Thank you!

Comment: @redexp Yes, it is also better supported (IE-wise). A lot of people in the JS community is against `__proto__` because of it being writable and I knew I'd get some hate for mentioning it, but I justwanted to highlight it as a possibility. I'd prefer the ES5 standard `Object.getPrototypeOf` alternative of course.